# ASIC Miner Block Erupter & bfgminer: "no devices found"

Tags: asic, bfgminer

Bit of an experiment.

I have 2 x ASIC Miner Block Erupter 333Mh/s Rev. 3.00 plugged into powered USB ports.

I've downloaded and installed CP210x_Universal_Windows_Driver from https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers.

I see:

[image]

If I run bfgminer, I receive an error `"no devices found. Press 'M' and '+' to add"`. I press `M`, then `+`, but no devices are detected.

Help appreciated.

[This is the tutorial I was following](http://www.bitcoinrigs.org/mining-resource/setup-asic-block-erupter-using-bfgminer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following the [ASIC instructions](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README.ASIC#L248) provided with BFGMiner

> These will autodetect if supported by the device; otherwise, you need to use
>   the '--scan-serial erupter:' option to tell BFGMiner what device to
>   probe; if you know you have no other serial devices, or only ones that can
>   tolerate garbage, you can use '--scan-serial erupter:all' to probe all serial
>   ports. They communicate with the Icarus protocol, which has some additional
>   options in README.FPGA

Try adding `--scan-serial-erupter:all` to the command for starting BFGMiner.

Comment: Do you know if BFGminer monitors the temperature of the devices?

Comment: I've added a question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66284/does-bfgminer-halt-processing-if-asic-miners-reach-a-high-temperature).