# Does BFGminer halt processing if ASIC miners reach a high temperature?

Tags: bfgminer

From the [README](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README) of BFGminer, I see:

```
The totals line shows the following:
 6/32   75.0C | 171.3/170.8/171.2Gh/s | A:729 R:8+0(.01%) HW:0/.81%

Each column is as follows:
  The number of devices and processors currently mining
  Hottest temperature reported by any processor
```

I don't see the temperature column.

Does this mean I have the incorrect Windows drivers?

Does it mean I need to pass a parameter to BFGminer?

Comment: Your temperature is 75.0C

Answer (score 0):

Not all miners return temperature information, it's only shown when available.

[image]

For example with a Block Erupter, there's none to show.

Comment: So what are my options for using the Block Erupters? If I leave them overnight, can they be damaged by overheating?

Comment: There's no point in using them, they make something like $0.00000048 a day.

Comment: I don't mind, I'm running an experiment.